# Play2 add new field to JsObject

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, jsobject

Is it possible to add new field to JsObject?

```
val jsonObj = Json.obj()
jsonObj.put("field" -> 100) <==== Somthing like this
```

I have a lot of methods that add new fields. How can I dynamically create JsObject?

Comment: I found something like this: jsonObj ++= Json.obj("field" -> 100)
Do I always have to create new JsObject?

Comment: Yes you do. `play.api.libs.json...` objects are immutable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can add a new field using the "+" method. Note that the object is immutable, so this will create a new copy of the JsObject with the added field:

```
val obj = Json.obj()
// obj - {}
val newObj = obj + ("name" -> JsString("Kip"))
// newObj - {"name":"Kip"}
```

Comment: You might be tempted to try, after looking at the source of JsObject +
val newObj = obj + ("name", JsString("Kip"))
But if you run -Xlint in the compiler option, you will get this warning: Adapting argument list by creating a 2-tuple: this may not be what you want.